# EKF Design And System Augmentation Bearings Only Tracking

Tags: control, matlab, filtering, kalman-filter

I am hoping someone can help me with some guidance or knowledge on the matter. Basically im setting up a "Bearings Only Tracking" simulation using the EKF/UKF toolbox within Matlab. I have a base system (See below) but require the system to be augmented to build a 4 state velocity model...

My Question/Issue is how is this augmentation done? and what is the significance of adding the additional velocity state.

**System Given**
[image]

Comment: In (5.1) \$w_k\$ is a \$2 \times 1\$ vector. in (5.2) \$x_k\$ is augmented to a \$4 \times 1\$ vector. What is \$w_k\$ augmented into ?

Comment: What are the measurements in this system ? \$w_k\$ ? Augmentation may be  way to introduce *a-priori estimate* and *posteriori estimate* ?